# How do I load association data in an Ecto changeset?

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

My group and I are using Phoenix and Ecto for a web app I'm making.

Our issue is that one of our model's changeset validations is dependent on an attribute of a child association. We should not be able to update the record if a boolean value is set to true in the child association.

However, we are not guaranteed that the changeset will always be called with a struct that preloads the association that we need. We want to avoid making a Repo.preload call in the model as much as possible because of separation of concerns, and we know this may set a precedent for poor coding practices in the future.

Any opinions or ideas would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

As of Phoenix 1.3, this is now trivial to accomplish. With the introduction of contexts, a context function can be written for preload which can be called from the controller!